# Rails check for duplicate models

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid4

I did a mistake in my rails app, and I didn't enforce the uniqueness of logins. Now I'd like to clean this mess by finding and removing duplicates (manually) in my code.

Is there a nice command I could enter in the Rails console that would let me find those duplicates ? Eg. find two users with the same login, and maybe make an array of array of duplicates ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your model is `User` and you are looking for duplicate attribute `login`, you should be able to do something like this:

```
User.find_by_sql("SELECT u1.id, u1.login FROM users u1 LEFT JOIN users u2 WHERE u1.login=u2.login AND u1.id!=u2.id ORDER BY u1.login, u1.id")
```

Of course, you can change the select to include whatever attributes you will need in order to decide what to do about the duplicates.

**EDIT** for Mongoid, [look at this link](http://blog.mongolab.com/2014/03/finding-duplicate-keys-with-the-mongodb-aggregation-framework/)

Comment: I don't think you can use sql queries with mongoid :)

Comment: Sorry @Cyril feeling bad that I answerbombed your question :(  I am not so familiar with `Mongoid` but found [this answer](http://blog.mongolab.com/2014/03/finding-duplicate-keys-with-the-mongodb-aggregation-framework/) which looks promising for your use case.  Hope it helps...

Comment: Sorry, for some reason I didn't get notified of answers. I'll have a look.

Comment: Yes thank you, your link was helpful, I will edit your answer to add it.